# How to export Access table to csv file with a custom header line?

Tags: ms-access, csv, export

I have a table with 13 columns of data that I need to export to an CSV file, which I can do with no problem from code using TransferText, but the tricky part is that the person receiving the file requires that the first line of the CSV have a custom header message that is only 3 fields.  So it needs to look like this:

```
"CompanyName", "Date", "Version"
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
```

I tried to use a UNION query, but it requires that both data sources have the same number of columns and I can't have 13 columns in the first line.  Does anyone have a trick for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gary,

You can use the Scripting.FileSystem object to write to / manipulate the text file after the transfer text.

See the following link for a basic introduction. Some judicious further Googling should get you what you want.

http://www.ezidata.com.au/tutorials/Working_with_Text_Files.html

Hope that helps,

Ash

p.s. or you could just have another 10 blank columns in the first part of your union...

Comment: I'll check the link, thanks.  As for the 10 columns, I would do that if I could get the first line without the extra 10 commas for the empty fields.  They only want 3.

Comment: My tongue was firmly in cheek when I wrote that postscript :-)

Comment: Ah...I was able to use file system objects to create the CSV file, write the first line, then loop through my dataset and append each row (with the 13 columns).  I was just hoping there was a trick for adding a custom first line without all of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Garry,

I think that's not possible. Because your field separator (,) indicates 13 columns.
So the export will result in only the first 3 columns with a name.
What if the you change the , between the numbers with a - ?

1-2-3-4,5-6-7-8,9-10-11-12-13

hope this will solve your problem

LeBro